# How do I configure a external RTC that uses 3-wire SPI for the LPC 2387?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, rtc, lpc

Here is the link to the datasheet of the RTC [PT7C4302](http://www.pericom.com/assets/Datasheets/PT7C4302.pdf).

I can do it with MISO, MOSI, but SISO I have no idea how to do. Some similar code examples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tie the MOSI and MISO lines together and follow the protocol in the product's datasheet which will ensure a half-duplex mode of your SPI peripheral. Note that the RST signal is high when you talk to the RTC so you need to invert your CS somehow.

MISO tied to MOSI might make it hard to talk to other devices on the same bus.

One way to avoid issues would be to bit-bang the interface. I suppose it's not possible to use another RTC?

Comment: I wish it was possible, but it would require significant hardware modifications.

Comment: When you say tie them together do you mean connect the RTC data line physically to two pins for MOSI and MISO?

Comment: Yes, something like the Figure-2 here: http://www.totalphase.com/support/kb/10059/

Comment: This is on an existing embedded board. There is no way to do this because the leads are already connected with traces.

Comment: Ok then how is the RTC connected to your SPI peripheral currently?

Comment: It is connected to P0 pin 7 for RST' (pin 78), P0 pin 8 for IO (pin 77), and P0 pin 9 SCLK (pin  76). There are only 3 wires currently connected. Apologies for the delay in responding.

Comment: You haven't made clear what you are using as the SPI master! Without that, the above comment means very little. You should just tell me in terms of SPI and not the specifics of your particular microcontroller.

If my answer has been useful to you, could you please upvote it?